# phpStorm loses permissions during sftp deployment

Tags: deployment, file-permissions, phpstorm

I use phpStorm on a mac using the deployment function with SFTP. Today I noticed, that file permissions get lost when I do that. Some of my local files have the execution bit set, but it is not set on the remote server.

In the deployment options I have disabled "Override default permissions" and did not have it enabled ever before.

What to do? Googled the world but could not find something that hooks into the deployment process of phpStorm. That is automatically triggering the deployment on save for instance. Found a solution with rsync and phing (http://www.ibresources.com/technical/programming/rsync-with-phpstorm), but for this solution, I have to press an extra key, what I do not want ( lazy bitch, I know ;-) ).

If there is no solution I am about to upload manually with rsync, which keeps the permissions and rely on the rest of the deployment features of phpStorm. The "Upload"-function is useless then.

Does anybody face the same problem? What to do about it?

Cheers,
Thomas

Comment: Found a way using file watchers: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/03/file-watchers-in-webstormphpstorm-6-a-k-a-background-tasks/

With this, I can trigger rsync whenever a file changes. Seems to work so far. Further solutions are welcome, though.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old thread. However;

To preserve RWX permissions of files on upload this can be defined in `PHPStorm Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment | Options`.

You will need to activate the check box for "Override default permissions on files" and open the options dialog to complete.

Please reference [the manual at](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/files-folders-default-permissions-dialog.html).

Comment: This is not the answer, because when one checks for "Override default permissions on files" and eg sets +x to owner, every file gets new permission. OP asked for sustaining file permissions between dev and deployment machines.